# ¿Como puedo definir una función resuelta mediante array asociativo?

Tags: php, array

Necesito hacer una función que al pasar un numero del mes, me devuelva el nombre del mes, la estación a la que pertenece y los días que tiene, mediante un array asociativo.
PD: Soy totalmente nuevo en lenguaje php y cualquier ayuda aunque sea mínima será bien recibida, ¡gracias!

```
$mes=[

    '1'=>[
        'mes'=>'ene',
        'dias'=>31,
        'estacion'=>'invierno'
    ],
    '2'=>[
        'mes'=>'feb',
        'dias'=>'28/29',
        'estacion'=>'invierno'
    ],
];
```

Cuando pongo el echo para mostrar en pantalla no me muestra las fechas.

```
echo mes['2']['dias'];
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Qué dificultad concreta tienes con lo que has intentado?

Comment: He logrado completar el array asociativo pero como ves en el codigo de arriba no responde al llamado

Comment: Estas nombrando mal la variable mes en el echo te falta el $. `echo $mes['2']['dias']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu función podría quedar así (he puesto comentarios pertinentes dentro del código para que puedas entender lo que se hace en cada momento).

```
/*
    *Esta es la función que recibe en parámetro el número a buscar
*/
function mesInfo($mNumber) {
    /*Completar tu array con los meses ... */
    $mes=[

        '1'=>[
            'mes'=>'ene',
            'dias'=>31,
            'estacion'=>'invierno'
        ],
        '2'=>[
            'mes'=>'feb',
            'dias'=>'28/29',
            'estacion'=>'invierno'
        ],
    ];
    /*
        Verificamos si el número pasado se encuentra en el array
    */
    if (array_key_exists($mNumber,$mes)) {
        $info="";
        foreach ($mes[$mNumber] as $k=>$v){
            /*Concatenamos las llaves y valores en la variable $info*/
            $info.="$k: $v".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }else{
        $info="$mNumber no es un mes válido".PHP_EOL;
    }
    /*Devolvemos lo que haya resultado*/
    return $info;
}
```

Ahora hacemos varias pruebas de la función:

```
echo mesInfo(1);
```

**Salida:**

```
mes: ene
dias: 31
estacion: invierno
```

---

```
echo mesInfo(2);
```

**Salida:**

```
mes: feb
dias: 28/29
estacion: invierno
```

---

```
echo mesInfo('aaa');
```

**Salida:**

```
aaa no es un mes válido
```

---

```
echo mesInfo(23);
```

**Salida:**

```
23 no es un mes válido
```